# “no module named xlwings” error on Windows when calling the Python script within XLSM file

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am getting started with xlwings and I get this error when trying to setup the sample application described in the xlwings example. (https://www.xlwings.org/examples)

I am on Python 3.6

---

### Error

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

File "c:\users\downloads\python\fibonacci\fibonacci.py", line 7, in

```
import xlwings as xw
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlwings'

I know xlwings is installed fine:

```
>>> import xlwings
>>> xlwings.__version__
>>> '0.10.4'
```

Any help with what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

EDIT: I think that VBA Macro is unable to see my libraries in the Python installation because its unable to find numpy also if I import numpy in the script that is being called from VBA. But I am still unsure how to fix this

Comment: How are you executing the `fibonacci.py` script?

Comment: If the interpreter that you can start by simply typing `python` at the command prompt doens't have xlwings installed, you need to point `PYTHON_WIN` to the location of the interpreter, see http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/vba.html#settings

Comment: @JohnGordon Through excel (calling a VBA function). Thanks Felix that worked. I made the change in the xlwings.bas file and it runs now.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the 'ModuleNotFoundError' with xlwings occurs when I work with IDLE 3.7 (64-bit) but is solved when I switch to IDLE 3.8 (32-bit).